# Ошибка при наследовании функции с декоратором Python

Tags: python, функции, классы, наследование, декоратор

У меня есть три класса с одинаковыми параметрами `id`. Я хочу, чтобы они наследовались от одного базового класса и наследовали функции (getter-setter), обернутые в декораторы `@property` и `@id.setter` (встроенные в Python). То есть наследовали то поведение, которое должно воспроизводиться при чтении-записи переменной.

Пример базового класса:

```
class A:

    def __init__(self, id: int):
        self.id = id

    @property
    def id(self) -> int:
        return self.id

    @id.setter
    def id(self, val: int):
        self.__id = val
```

Пример дочернего класса:

```
class B(A):

    def do_something(self):
         print("Hello")
```

Пример `main.py`:

```
b_obj = B(123)
print(b_obj.id)
```

На выходе я получаю ошибку переполнения стека рекурсии:

```
File "main.py", line 15, in id
return self.id
[Previous line repeated 996 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

В чем заключается проблема и как можно решить поставленную задачу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этом месте возникает рекурсия, так как идет обращение к этому же `property`:

```
@property
def id(self) -> int:
    return self.id    # тут произойдет вызов этой же функции
```

Исправьте, чтоб обращаться к приватному полю объекта:

```
@property
def id(self) -> int:
    return self.__id
```

Comment: Спасибо! Глаз замылился, сам не заметил :)